# Cosa significa "pregio" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Rinascimento privato* di Maria Bellonci ho letto:

> I figli maschi hanno occupato spazi ampi nella mia vita. Da giovane il pensiero di loro prevaleva in me. Quando fui più matura in età e in esperienza occuparono ciascuno un posto preminente ma diverso: mi appassionava disegnare le loro azioni, seguirli e formarli a mio modo. Essere io donna divenne allora un **pregio** d'autorità afferrato e cresciuto a goccia a goccia in me stessa.

Ho cercato il vocabolo "pregio" in alcuni dizionari ma, tra le molte accezioni che appaiono, non riesco a vedere a quale corrisponda l'uso che se ne fa nel brano precedente. Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire il mio dubbio?

Comment: Forse è usato in un senso simile a “privilegio”?? Commento – mi rendo conto – del tutto inutile: vedere questi estratti mi fa passare qualsiasi voglia di leggere la Bellonci...

Comment: Direi anch'io che significa qualcosa come "privilegio", "merito", "vanto". Non so se questo può essere utile: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/privilegio_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/.

Answer (score 2):

Il significato del termine nel brano corrisponde all'accezione numero 9 della [voce "pregio" sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI14/00000131.jpg), che precisa che questo aggettivo può essere accompagnato da un complemento di specificazione:

> **9.** Buona reputazione; fama onorevole, nomea positiva; gloria, lustro. 
>   [...] 
>       – In relazione con un compl. di specificazione. 
>       *Chiaro Davanzati*, 1-55: Usate propiamente veritate, / se fin pregio volete di bontate. *Dante*, 1-2: Savete giudicar vostra ragione, / o om che pregio di saver portate; / per che, vitando aver con voi quistione, / com so rispondo a le parole ornate. *Idem*, *Purg*., 8-129: Vostra gente onrata non si sfregia / del pregio de la borsa e de la spada. *Fiori di filosafi*, 158: Chi vuole pregio di iustizia, usila ne' suoi offici. *Livio volgar*., 1-72: Tullo regnò con grande pregio di armi anni trentadue. *Ceffi*, XXI-25-46: Voi possiate tornare al vostro albergo con buona nominanza e grande pregio e di misericordia e di giustizia.  *Tasso*, 6-72: Il titolo tu d'esser pudica / sì poco stimi, e d'onestate il pregio, / che te n'andrai fra nazion nemica, / notturna amante, a ricercar dispregio? *L. Adimari*, 159: Già in pregio d'onestà visse laudabile  l'alto nome di Porzia e di Sulpizia.

Come specifica questo vocabolario  un po' più avanti, questa accezione può anche avere la sfumatura di

> – Merito degno di onore; vanto.

Cioè, la narratrice si sta riferendo all'autorità come una qualità positiva di sé stessa, un merito degno di onore, di buona reputazione, associato al fatto di essere donna.